# How to unselect a feature

Tags: openlayers-3

I am doing a maplayer switch function but when I switch the layer, the selected feature is not unselected. May I know how to unselect a feature in openlayer 3.

```
$("#show-field-map").click(function(event) {
    map.removeLayer(subbasinJsonp);
    map.addLayer(fieldJsonp);
    $('#show-subbasin-map').attr("disabled", false);
    $('#show-field-map').attr("disabled", true);
});

$("#show-subbasin-map").click(function(event) {
    map.removeLayer(fieldJsonp);
    map.addLayer(subbasinJsonp);
    $('#show-field-map').attr("disabled", false);
    $('#show-subbasin-map').attr("disabled", true);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

The `Select` interaction carries collection of features:

```
var select = new ol.interation.Select();
var features = selectInteraction.getFeatures();
```

You can call `clear()` on that selection to unselect all features:

```
features.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

For OpenLayers v7:

First declare the select

```
let select = new Select({
    layers: [someVectorLayer],
});
```

Then remove it:

```
map.removeInteraction(select);
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, I would rather choose a way of removing interaction and assigning it again, like it is [here](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/select-features.js).

Comment: Now the provided link is broken. Would be better to provide some more information beside the reference links.